# How to get response and show from backend in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```
data: function () {
    return {
      searchResults: []
    }

methods: {

show() {
      return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: this.url,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user-token')}`
        }
      })
          .then (function (response){
            return response.data['searchResults'];
          })
          .catch(e => { console.log(e) })
    },
}
```

I have an onClick button. When I click the button, the show function executed and it send get response to my spring boot. After that it retrieves some data as I see in console, but the data is not displayed in browser. How can I fix it? The data I get looks like this:

```
  JSON:
0: Object { "Code": "4326", code_color: 2, "name": "SomeName", … }
1: Object { "Code": "4326", code_color: 2, "name": "SomeName", … }
2: Object { "Code": "4326", code_color: 2, "name": "SomeName", … }
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the data you've provided isn't enough; How does your onclick event use show method? Where do you asign the returned data from server to searchResults in the components data? What's your template structure?

Comment: Thats the problem. I am having problem assigning retrieved data

Comment: Can you tell us what's the structure of returned data from server?

Comment: Array like this { "Code": "4326", code_color: 2, "name": "SomeName", … }

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the returned data from api call in the show method to searchResults in the components data, so instead of

```
return response.data['searchResult']
```

you can use

```
this.searchResults = response.data.searchResult
```

Comment: Great answer. Was gonna say the same. :)

Comment: Should I then loop through searchResults  with for loop to get the data in div?

Comment: @Kozi Since the data is an object and not an array, there is no need to use v-for (loop) and you can print what ever property that you want directly, like this: '<p>{{ searchResults.name }}</p>'; But if you want to use  a v-for loop, you should check the documentation to see how to use it with an object. Although I'm guessing that something isn't right here, since the search results are usually an array of objects and not a single object, so probably you should check your response format again

Comment: You are right, It is an array of objects

Comment: @Kozi So please edit your question and update the response format.